# python django cant access the other objects only the first object can access`

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

In my HTML file i have script tag that contains a variable called nameSearch this will get the value from the textboxt

HTML and Javascript:

```
            <!-- SEARCH BAR -->

<section class = "search_bar" id ="search_bar">
    <h1 class = "search_bar-h1">Find a Grave</h1>

    <form action="" class = "main_form">
        <input type="text" id = "name" placeholder="Full Name">
        <input type="button" name = "searchButton" value ="Start your Search" onclick="searched()">
    </form>
</section>

<section>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function searched(){
    nameSearched = document.getElementById('name').value;
        {% for names in name %}
            if ("{{ names.First }}" == nameSearched ){
                document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "{{ names.Last }}";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "none";
            }
    {% endfor %}
    }
</script>

    <h1 id = "dis">test</h1>
</section>
```

i want to use the variable nameSearched in my if statement in python but i dont know if its posible because its always return nothing.

Comment: Django template engine works only when page is rendering, after rendering you must manage your variables with javascript variables. Your problem causes from this.

Comment: how can i do that, sorry im new in django.